# Package hyperref Warning due to the usage of formula in author list

Tags: hyperref

I am using overleaf. The author list in my paper is as follows:

```
\author{A$^\dag$, B\footnote{Corresponding author}$^{\ddag,\S}$, C$^\dag$, D$^\dag$}
\affiliation{
  \institution{$^\dag$E\\
  $^\ddag$F; $^\S$G}
  \country{}}
\email{xxxxxx}
```

And I got the following warnings:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `math shift' on input line 148.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `superscript' on input line 148.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `\@ifnextchar' on input line 148.
```

I tried the solution `\texorpdfstring` but it didn't work. I think I may use it in the wrong way. Should it be like `A\texorpdfstring{$^\dag$}`? How to fix these warnings?

Comment: \texorpdfstring takes two arguments, the first the "tex" and the second the "pdf" (bookmark) text. That's why it is "tex or pdf"

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you. I fixed it by using ```A\texorpdfstring{$^\dag$}{}```